# How to drag/copy Excel formulae to include cells at specified intervals

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet in which I want start column D with the following formula:

`=AVERAGE(C7:C10)`

I want to be able to drag down column D to give the following formulae:

```
=AVERAGE(C11:C14)
=AVERAGE(C15:C18)
=AVERAGE(C19:C22)
```

etc.

However, if I just naively drag down, instead, I get:

```
=AVERAGE(C8:C11)
=AVERAGE(C9:C12)
=AVERAGE(C10:C13)
```

How can I change this behavior?

Comment: Would the use of a helper column to accomplish this be acceptable?

Comment: Yes but only if the helper column can also be generated in an automated way since I have a lot of rows to get through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In column D enter

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET($C$1,4*ROW(C1)+2,0,4))
```

Then when you drag it down column D, each successive cell will have the reference incremented by 4.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure which cells are now being averaged. How can I be averaging `C7:10`, then `C11:C14` etc. for D7 and D8 respectively?

Comment: OK what works is: `=AVERAGE( OFFSET($C$1,4*ROW(C1)+2,0,4) )`

Comment: Row(C1) is a good tweak to my formula since then it doesn't depend on being entered in D1. I will edit the answer to include this change.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that the size of the ranges remain constant. If, for example, column G is unpopulated then G1=7;G2=11. Select both cells and pull the fill handle down as far as needed. The formula for D1 is`=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("C"&G1&":C"&G1+3))`, which can be filled down as far as needed.

Comment: Using Excel 2010 I also get #REF if there is nothing in cell G1, however provided there is a value of 7 in G1 then I get the average of C7 through C10. That said I would accept, and upvoted, @John Coleman's answer, it is efficient and even elegant.